# Stacked bar chart with Line dataset, line dont follow the target size

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2, primereact

I have this stacked bar chart and a line dataset together, but as you can see on the next image, I have a bug numbers at bar chartm and on my line dataset I get numbers between 0 and 100 and a i join the number with the Percentage symbol, but my line keep on bottom because it is loking for all chart data, how can I condicer only the 0 as min and 100 as max to line data has the correct height?

[Chart Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG2lo.png)

this is my dataset line config

```
{
            data: lineNumbers,
            borderColor: EChartTheme.LIGHT_RED_BAR,
            type: 'line',
            tension: 0.3,
            pointRadius: 0,
            datalabels: {
                align: 'right',
                offset: 8,
                borderRadius: 2,
                font: {
                    size: 11,
                },
                backgroundColor: EChartTheme.LIGHT_GRAY,
                padding: 2,
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderColor: (context: any) => {
                    const currentNumber = lineNumbers[context.dataIndex]
                    if (currentNumber == nearestToFiveNumer) return EChartTheme.RED_BAR
                    return ''
                },
                formatter(value, context) {
                    const formated = numberFormat(value, 1)
                    return `${formated.replace(',', '.')}%`
                },
            },
        },
```

I looked the line data config.